# It is possible to use git as sql database

Tags: sql, git, firebase, github, aws-sdk

I know it's not logical question,but if git is best solution for code save and work around with team and its use for many things.

So why not its use like sql database.
Or just store small amount of mobile data like firebase uses.

Because as  I read this article
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www3.dbmaestro.com/blog/using-git-for-database-why-and-how%3fhs_amp=true
I am little bit confused,why git not focused on use its self modifying itself as SQL database or like server storage like firebase and AWS.

Again I ask,its not possible now,but I just ask,because I am so curious about this why it's not possible .

Comment: Git would be better described as an object store, I think, or perhaps a graph database.  Although the data could be modeled as a relational database, I don't think that is the most natural method.  Plus, Git already has an interface which is nothing like SQL.

Comment: echo Gordon + It can be used as a database but not like SQL database.

Comment: It's like asking why not use a pair of pliers when what you need is a screwdriver.  It might be different if you had a specific implementation or use case you wanted to discuss (though still I'm not sure that would be on topic for SO) - but as asked, this question is unfocused to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: Look into fossil if you want version control built on top of a sql database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, git has no interpreter for SQL language, so it wouldn't be an SQL database. But why can't it be a NoSQL database?

Because there are already other implementations of databases that solve the needs of a database much better than Git can.

[Git as a NoSql database](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/10/13/git-nosql-database/) is a pretty thorough blog post describing the possibility of using Git as a NoSQL database. It has a lot of drawbacks, including but not limited to:

- Merge conflicts occur. Sometimes these require human intervention.
  That would basically cause the database to halt until someone could
  clean it up.
- Queries and updates can only search by key. There’s no concept of
  indexing by some other attribute, and there’s no concept of
  set-oriented queries like in SQL.
- Write performance sucks because every commit goes to disk.
- Updating
  data create copies. This causes storage requirements to increase
  rapidly, until `git gc` consolidates space.

You can also ask why can't a screwdriver be used as a hammer? Maybe you could tap nails in very slowly and carefully, but it would make a lousy hammer compared to, you know, a hammer. It's clear the screwdriver is designed for a different purpose.

Comment: I wrote the answer above in 2018 on Quora, so I am copying my own content here. https://www.quora.com/Why-hasnt-there-been-a-major-database-that-sits-on-top-of-Git/answer/Bill-Karwin